# Implementacion de CICD en microservicios

Tags: devops, github-actions, integración-continua

Estoy explorando el mundo DevOps y CICD.

Actualmente, tengo un workflow de github action donde al realizar un pull request se ejecuta dicho workflow el cual compila el proyecto y lo publica, si el workflow falla se ejecuta otro workflow que realiza un rollback.

Lo que ahora quiero hacer es al tener 3 apis y 2 proyectos web los cuales consumen las 3 apis, al publicar una actualización en 1 o más apis y en uno de los proyectos web se corra un workflow por cada repositorio, pero si alguno de ellos falla le notifique a los demás de que término con un error y los demás workflow realicen un rollback.

Esto es posible utilizando github action o tendría que utilizar otra herramienta como kurbenetes etc. si alguien puede orientarme o compartirme donde puedo encontrar información relacionada.